# How to avoid this error ?Unable to run job: error: no suitable queues

Tags: qsub

I have the following command to submit multiple jobs

```
qsub  -l hostname=cicd5500d\|cicdrel57b\|cicdrel57c\|cicdrel57d\|cicdrel57e\|cicdrel57f  -V
```

When i try to submit 2 or 3 jobs it works fine. But when job count is greater then 30 it fails during submitting process with the following error

Unable to run job: error: no suitable queues.

May this be caused by grid settings what can I do in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that one of machines was removed from grid. If user specifies host list for qsub command then he /she should be sure that all hosts are in grid.

This link helped me to find solution
http://wiki.crc.nd.edu/wiki/index.php/FAQ#.27Unable_to_run_job:_error:_no_suitable_queues.27_Message_When_Submitting_Job_Script